# Bootstrap multiselect with dividers

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-multiselect

I'm trying to use the Bootstrap multiselect but I need to place dividers (this bars) between the  elements. Here is the markup that I have so far. I tried placing  because I read somewhere that you can do this with the bootstrap select but it does not look like it works with the bootstrap multiselect. I end up getting a checkbox but with no text next to it. I would like a simple bar or line to separate the groups.

```
<select id="team_filter_1" class="col-md-9" multiple="multiple">
<option value="studio_1" data-type="studio">All Eidos-Montréal</option>
<optgroup label="Games">
    <option value="game_0" data-type="game">All Games</option>
    <option value="game_1" data-type="game">DX:MD</option>
    <option  data-divider="true"></option>
    <option value="game_1_scenario_2" data-type="game">DX:MD - Sc.1_March</option>
    <option value="game_1_scenario_3" data-type="game">DX:MD - Sc.2_Sept</option>
    <option value="game_2" data-type="game">DX:NG2</option>
    <option value="game_3" data-type="game">DX:LIVE</option>
    <option value="game_4" data-type="game">TRXMTL</option>
</optgroup>
<option data-divider="true"></option>
<optgroup label="Support departments">
    <option value="department_8" data-type="support">Cinematics</option>
    <option value="department_9" data-type="support">Marketing</option>
</optgroup>
<option data-divider="true"></option>
<optgroup label="G&A departments">
    <option value="department_1" data-type="ga">HR</option>
    <option value="department_2" data-type="ga">Finance</option>
    <option value="department_3" data-type="ga">IT</option>
    <option value="department_4" data-type="ga">Admin</option>
</optgroup>
<option data-divider="true"></option>
<optgroup label="Other departments">
    <option value="department_5" data-type="other">Global HR</option>
    <option value="department_6" data-type="other">Global IT</option>
    <option value="department_7" data-type="other">QA</option>
</optgroup>
```

I use this jQuery script to activate it:

```
$("select[id*='team_filter']").multiselect({
        nonSelectedText: 'All',
        numberDisplayed: 1,
        nSelectedText: 'selected',
        allSelectedText: 'All'
    });
```

I'm using https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1zuj6w7h/1/ I don't see any issue with your markup, except that `<optgroup>` includes a divider-line, so you have 2 lines between some options.. Are you using the plugin at: http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/ ?

Comment: It's the bootstrap-multiselect.css that I'm actually using. It's not from the link you provided. I clicked Run in jsFiddle and the Result pane stays empty.

Comment: Hmm. I'm not familiar with that library. Could you set up a JSFiddle to better represent your issue? Right now, I don't see the problem.

Comment: I updated https://jsfiddle.net/1zuj6w7h/2/  You`ll see that the dividers show up as blank lines with just a checkbox

Comment: There's nothing in that documentation about `<option data-divider="true"></option>`... If you use the plugin I linked they work, but this `bootstrap-multiselect` doesn't show their usage anywhere.

Comment: When I click on your jsFiddle, I get nothing in the Result pane. I'm new to jsFiddle so maybe I'm using is wrong? I click on the Run button on the top left but nothing appears in the Result pane.

Comment: Really? You don't see this:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5Peq.png ? Perhaps try a different browser, or make sure Scripts are allowed. I don't know why it would work for me but not for you.

Comment: That's exactly what I want. But I have to get it to work using https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect

Comment: Yeah, I understand that, but I'm afraid the documentation from that library is lacking (typos, unclosed code-fragments, missing examples, etc) and I can't find a way to do it... Sorry. Any reason you **have** to use one library over the other? I would understand if it were a customer condition that you have to follow.

Comment: Unfortunately, it`s a customer condition. I'll try to convince them to update. If you put your response as an answer I'd be more than happy to mark it as an answer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sure, I can add it. And I understand; customer needs come before all else (even if it isn't the right answer). Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the library from http://silviomoreto.github.io/bootstrap-select/ will allow the use of `<option data-divider="true"></option>` or `<optgroup>...</optgroup>` for displaying bars between options:

```
<select id="team_filter_1" class="selectpicker" multiple="multiple">
    <option value="studio_1" data-type="studio">All Eidos-Montréal</option>
    <optgroup label="Games">
        <option value="game_0" data-type="game">All Games</option>
        <option value="game_1" data-type="game">DX:MD</option>
        <option  data-divider="true"></option>
        <option value="game_1_scenario_2" data-type="game">DX:MD - Sc.1_March</option>
        <option value="game_1_scenario_3" data-type="game">DX:MD - Sc.2_Sept</option>
        <option value="game_2" data-type="game">DX:NG2</option>
        <option value="game_3" data-type="game">DX:LIVE</option>
        <option value="game_4" data-type="game">TRXMTL</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Support departments">
        <option value="department_8" data-type="support">Cinematics</option>
        <option value="department_9" data-type="support">Marketing</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="G&A departments">
        <option value="department_1" data-type="ga">HR</option>
        <option value="department_2" data-type="ga">Finance</option>
        <option value="department_3" data-type="ga">IT</option>
        <option value="department_4" data-type="ga">Admin</option>
    </optgroup>
    <optgroup label="Other departments">
        <option value="department_5" data-type="other">Global HR</option>
        <option value="department_6" data-type="other">Global IT</option>
        <option value="department_7" data-type="other">QA</option>
    </optgroup>
</select>
```

See this [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/1zuj6w7h/1/) for a working example.